# Use of old single band router

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireless-router

I am using an old single band dlink dir 600l router. However it's quite old and doesn't provide a good range these days. Recently I also bought a Samsung Smart TV and thinking to buy a new dual band router from Tplink.

Can I use the current router with new setup? Will it help in extending the range or speed? I have heard of cascading the routers but not sure if it will work in this case.

Comment: You really need to describe how you are wanting to integrate it into your network.   It can be used to boost your network range (but not really speed) in some cases - mainly where you have ethernet cable running between 2 distant points in your house.

Comment: I will want to connect both routers in LAN and then use them wirelessly

Comment: @SankretR - that statement is meaningless.  A LAN is a Local Area Network - it says nothing about how you want to construct it.   How do you intend to actually connect the interfaces - Generally you can't have access points connecting wirelessly to access points.

Comment: I mean I want to connect both the routers using LAN cable. Create 2 seperate networks of 5 and 2.4 GHz. And while using the internet on my devices I want to connect to either of these networks. What should be the primary router in this case which is connected to internet directly?

Comment: Yes, this can work.  You would need to disable all the router functionality in 1 router (especially DHCP) and just use it as a an Access Point/Switch.  It would make sense to use the newer router as the router and the older one as the Access point because the newer one can most likely push more packets per second - of-course this answer may vary depending on where the signal enters your premises and where most of the usage is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use your D-Link router as another access point for your WiFi.

If you want to turn your D-Link DIR-600L router into an access point, you should check out hciguy's guide to [Turning D-Link Router's into access points](http://www.hciguy.com/2010/07/19/how-to-turn-your-d-link-router-into-an-access-point-repeater-to-extend-your-wireless-coverage/)

Comment: Thanks for providing the reference. As a matter of doubt I also wanted to clarify since the dlink router is single band and the new one would be dual band will cause any compatibility issues?